# How to compile and import Java class with lein-figwheel?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, leiningen, clojure-java-interop, figwheel

I added   `:java-source-paths ["src/java"]` to my project.clj, *lein uberjar* works but when running *lein figwheel* I get the following error:

```
Figwheel: Cutting some fruit, just a sec ...
Figwheel: Validating the configuration found in project.clj
Figwheel: Configuration Valid :)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: projectc.java.gcloud.DataStore, compiling:(projectc/gcloud/datastore.clj:1:1)
```

I added this to the ':uberjar` section

```
:prep-tasks ["javac" "compile" ["cljsbuild" "once" "min"]]
```

Any clues to how to solve this?

Comment: Did you have a look at [this](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel/issues/68)?

Comment: Just to to be sure, I assume you know that figwheel is usually used to run Clojurescript, and therefore Javascript, and that normally Java wouldn't have any role in this process because Java doesn't run in browsers (unless you do something like running an applet).  Java *could* have some role with figwheel, I guess, since the Clojurescript compiler is written in Clojure, so you could do something with Java before/after/while compiling Clojurescript.  If you know all of this already, and know that Java is what you need with figwheel in this case, ignore this.  Maybe it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Figwheel (and the ClojureScript compiler) compiles your code, it will process all clj files that it is given, to compile macros that are in `clj` files. It looks like Figwheel is trying to compile a file which is using a class which isn't on the Classpath? Is it possible to include that class, or exclude the Clojure file from the Figwheel compilation? Perhaps try building that Java project as a JAR and including it as a dependency as a test?

It's a little hard to tell with not very much information, this [issue](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel/issues/68) also looks like it might be relevant?